why the same unity sorting layer settings showing different result for identical prefab objects?
I am making a 2D card game. Each card is a prefab object, with the rectangular card background in the default layer and the text as a canvas child in the UI layer. I ran into a problem with the text from one card overlapping the text from another card. This picture shows the problem.

I toggled with the layer settings and somehow managed to achieve the desired effect with one of the card prefabs. This picture shows the result I am trying to achieve.

I tried replicating the settings for the correct card prefab in the inspector.

Both green card prefabs have the exact same setting for the canvas and sprite renderer components, like in the screenshots above. However, I might have changed something else I'm not aware of because when I duplicated the prefab with the desired behavior, it worked.
Other than experimenting with layer settings, I tried using the API too as an alternative. This is a script I tried but it is not working because the canvas text sorting order does not get updated (and stays 0), while the background card prefab increments correctly. The result is the text is hidden behind the card background...
private SortingGroup sortingGroup;
private GameObject parentObject;
private void Awake()
{
    parentObject = this.gameObject;
    collider2d = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    canvas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCanvas").GetComponent<Canvas>();
    sortingGroup = GetComponent<SortingGroup>();

}   
public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    collider2d.enabled = false;
    // Bring the dragged card to the top
    if (sortingGroup != null)
    {
        sortingOrderCounter++;
        sortingGroup.sortingOrder = sortingOrderCounter;
        foreach (Canvas childCanvas in parentObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>())
        {
            childCanvas.overrideSorting = true;
            childCanvas.sortingOrder = sortingOrderCounter;
        }

    }
}

I need another solution because my canvas isn't a nested canvas, and the text is set to inactive when the card is flipped to the other side, then back to active again when flipped back, which makes it complicated. What's the easiest way to fix this problem? Thank you very much.

In short - you are trying to combine completely different elements that look similar. Canvas and sprite renderer use different rules of drawing.

okay, then how did i manage to get the desired effect somehow... and any ideas of a way to approach this? thank you for your time!

You need to select one system and use it. If you want to use canvas - use canvas and all the needed objects (like canvas labels, images, etc.), if you want to use world objects - use them. If your objects will use the same system - you will be able to sort them as you want.
